# first jest test is failing - trying to import react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've downloaded this https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet project and I've inserted a new button.
Now, am trying to learn how to create a jest test to see if the button exists.

The specific file I've hijacked is this:
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/toolbox/components/web/Toolbox.js

I've added a new button to the  _renderToolboxContent()  method.  This is what the rendered HTML looks like in part for this new button:

```
<div aria-label="Toggle MyCustomSVGButton" class="toolbox-button">
    <div>
        <div class="toolbox-icon">
            <div class="jitsi-icon">
                <svg height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 792.199 792.199">
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, based on other examples, I've cobbled together this jest test:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Toolbar from './react/features/toolbox/components/web/Toolbox.js';

test('Check for MyCustomSVGButton', () => {

   it('MyCustomSVGButton rendered', () => {
    expect(wrapper.contains(MyCustomSVGButton).toEqual(true));
    });
});
```

But when I run this, i get the following error:

```
> jest

 FAIL  ./app.test.js   ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /mnt/c/Users/jj/custom/jitsti-meet/app.test.js:1
    import * as React from 'react';
           ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

      at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1179:56)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       0 total Snapshots:   0 total Time:        4.124 s Ran all test suites. npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details. jj@lab:/mnt/c/Users/jj/custom/jitsti-meet$
```

This is what the package.json looks like in part:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.2.0",
    "clean-css-cli": "4.3.0",
    "css-loader": "3.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.3",
    "eslint": "5.6.1",
    "eslint-config-jitsi": "github:jitsi/eslint-config-jitsi#1.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.3.0",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "flow-bin": "0.104.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "jest": "^26.3.0",
    "jetifier": "1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "unorm": "1.6.0",
    "webpack": "4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . && flow",
    "postinstall": "jetify",
    "validate": "npm ls"
  },
```

**What I've tried**

Since this application uses babel i installed babel-jest as well, but its still failing.

I found the following file:
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L52

I'm currently comparing that with this:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack

But I can't say that I know exactly what I should be looking for .

Comment: Are there tests in that package you've based it on? *Do* you have any config to transform the source code?

Comment: no.  the only tests are the ones I've tried to create in the app.test.js file.  but all the logic that creates the toolbox / buttons are in the Toolbox.js file.

Comment: So what configuration do you have? Did you try any of the things the error suggests?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with React programming in general, but i did find this: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/webpack.config.js.  Will update my post with more details and questions

Comment: What node version are you on? Have you tried a newer, or older one?

Comment: @pinto, i'm using ubuntu 20.04 and have nodejs 10.19.0.  Did apt update and tried installing from apt.  Says it's already latest.  You think I need to change / try something else?